# Connecting Ionic 4 app to a WebSocket on the same network

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, websocket

Like the title says, I can't seem to be able to connect my Ionic 4 app to my LG TV which runs on the same network through a WebSocket.

I've tried a lot of methods, using cordova-advanced-websocket, SocketIO, WS, native WebSocket etc..

I've gone so far as to managing to connect to my TV but all I get in response is "invalid origin" . I know what this means but what I don't understand is, how to bypass that and also, how come I get it when my app runs on the same network? They're not the same IP's though 192.168.0.17:8100 ( device ) and 192.168.0.27:3000 ( TV )

I've been struggling over this for a couple of days and I'm almost ready to give up, however, I know it's possible, somehow, since some of the apps on the AppStore are able to connect to my TV and control it.

I don't have any code, it's literally just your standard `new WebSocket(ip)`
I have a script which works and I'm able to connect to the TV and send commands, however, this runs by starting a Node.JS server, thus why it's working.

I'm not looking to make it work in the browser or whatever, even if Ionic runs in the browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend and I ran into this exact problem today! For whatever reason, the TV refuses websocket connections unless the Origin header is set to null. You can trick the browser into sending a null origin by proxying websocket requests through an iframe that renders a data uri, like so:

```js
const doc = `
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.196:3000")
            ws.onopen = () => parent.postMessage("open", "*")
            window.onmessage = ({data}) => ws.send(data)
            ws.onmessage = ({data}) => parent.postMessage(data, "*")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
`

const iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
iframe.src = `data:text/html;base64,${btoa(doc)}`
document.body.appendChild(iframe)

iframe.onload = function() {
    // Receive responses from websocket via iframe
    window.onmessage = ({data}) => {
        console.log(`Received: ${data}`)
    }

    // Send requests to websocket via iframe
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }), '*');
}
```

Comment: OMG! Unfortunately, I gave up on the project due to this. Not sure if I want to pick it up again but I will run your code and if it works, I'll buy you a beer, or juice, whichever you prefer :) Thanks!